# Process.Start("chrome.exe","url") not working on Dotnet worker service after service hosted on windows

Tags: windows, .net-core, process, windows-services, backgroundworker

I have **Dotnet core Worker Service** application in the version 6.0.

I am trying to open a website using **System.Diagnostics.Process**. it is working fine when I am in debugging mode on visual studio, when I hosted service using below Command on windows.

```
SC create serviceName binpath="abc.exe"
```

Services working fine after hosting but Process.Start("","") not throwing any exception also not open any browser. there is no log on windows & event viewer.

any help on this will be appreciate.

1. Enable allow service to interact with desktop.
2. using processinfo to set UseShellExecute.

Comment: *Allow service to interact with desktop* is a legacy thing that no longer does what you want it to, a service is isolated and cannot interact with the current users desktop. Create a normal autostart exe that has the interactive code and have it talk with the service as necessary.

Comment: there is continuous evaluation over the exe. when we run it manually by double clicking on it. it is working as expected but when i hosted as service it's not working. 

User might forgot to start result into failure that why need to hosted as windows service which will run automatically once hosted even though when pc shutdown